Is <g:include> broken in Grails 6.2.1?
Upon upgrading to 6.2.1 the <g:include> tag isn't working.
I upgraded a 6.2.0 app to 6.2.1 and now my <g:include> tag isn't working.  I tested pretty well, adding text before and after, I even created a blank brand new project from Grails Forge, added an include and it doesn't work.
I don't know if there is a different place to report bugs.  I've just recently starting using Grails again.
Anyway, I was able to work around it by just including the content where I want it, but it would be nice if it worked.
Thanks.
Mick
